# Compare operator error

Tags: sql, function, postgresql, plpgsql

I have the following query in plpgsql:

```
FOR _t IN EXECUTE 'select distinct_network_point.id AS network_point_id
           from distinct_network_point, all_points_ordered
           where road_id='||road_id||' AND distinct_network_point.point = all_points_ordered.point AND all_points_ordered.point != st_setsrid(st_makepoint('||new_point||'),4326)
           order by st_distance(all_points_ordered.point,st_setsrid(st_makepoint('||new_point||'),4326))
           limit 1'
```

For some it is giving me the following error:

[image]

If I use this <> operator it will give me this than:

[image]

Can anyone explain what it really mean?. The query works fine in sql.

Comment: I have tried that already but thanks for your advice

Comment: I have updated the question to show the error when I tried the  <> operator. @bernie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're dealing with geometric types, neither the `!=` or `<>` operators are valid.

[Instead, please refer to the following list of geometric operators.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/functions-geometry.html)

In this case, since you want to check that two points are not the same, I believe you can use the *distance between* operator, `<->`, and check if the distance between your two points is greater than some sort of very small epsilon value.

Something like:

```
AND all_points_ordered.point <-> st_setsrid(st_makepoint('||new_point||'),4326) > 0.0001
```

Comment: Thankks very much for the suggestion @michaelfredrickson

Comment: I think it would be better to just cast them to text. `all_points_ordered.point::text<> st_setsrid(st_makepoint('||new_point||'),4326)::text`. It works always and might be faster